# How to find where an object is located in a list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a list "players" and i want to find if my player is

> players[0]

or

> players[1]

or whaterver. How do i do this?

Comment: Can you please do a 15 minute effort to ask your question with the correct info and code. We want to help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`List<T>.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-6.0) method that you can use.

Answer (score -1):

**use of linq command**

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

players.Add(new Player() { Id = "1", Name = "angle" });
players.Add(new Player() { Id = "2", Name = "cristin" });
players.Add(new Player() { Id = "2", Name = "robert" });

var finded= players.Where(x => x.Name == "cristin").FirstOrDefault();

public class Player
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. They wanted it o know if it was index 0 or 1. This only answers if it’s in the list and chances are this is not the most efficient at that either.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
public int GetIndex(List<PlayerClass> playersList, PlayerClass player)
{
    return playersList.FindIndex(a => a == player);
}
```

It should return -1 if the player is not in the list.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.